# Place data at pagelocked address without copying

Tags: numpy, optimization, ctypes, pycuda

I am developing a program on NVIDIA Jetson Nano which capture a frame from webcam/video using opencv. Afterwards, it does some computation on the frame on gpu. This is done for each frame. To reduce run time, I am using mapped memory avoiding explicit copy between host, and device. The problem is I still have to copy the frame to the shared pointer address i.e. HOST to HOST copy which takes a good amount of time. How can I cut/reduce this time OR if rephrased how can I update frame data at the shared memory location each time efficently?

Currently, I copy the frame to the shared address using `np.copyto`

```
frame = cap.read()
sharedadd = cuda.pagelocked_empty((1,3,500,500), dtype=np.float32),mem_flags=cuda.host_alloc_flags.DEVICEMAP) # allocate     mapped memory
np.copyto(sharedadd, frame.ravel()) # takes quite some time
```

I tried using `ctype` pointer to dereference the shared memory location and assign it new value. However, it expects the frame to be a ctype pointer too.

```
frame = cap.read()
sharedadd = cuda.pagelocked_empty((1,3,500,500),dtype=np.float32),mem_flags=cuda.host_alloc_flags.DEVICEMAP) # allocate mapped memory
c_float_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)
sharedptr = sharedadd.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)
ctypes.cast(ctypes.addressof(sharedptr), ?).contents # second argument is expected to be a ctype pointer to frame
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can I update frame data at the shared memory location each time efficently?

If I understand correctly, you want to access (and change) the content of the float array pointed to by `shared_ptr`.

Given:

```py
frame = cap.read()
sharedadd = cuda.pagelocked_empty((1,3,500,500),dtype=np.float32),mem_flags=cuda.host_alloc_flags.DEVICEMAP) # allocate mapped memory
c_float_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)
sharedptr = sharedadd.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)
```

You can access the content directly by indexing `shared_ptr`:

```py
float_1 = shared_ptr[0]  # read
shared_ptr[0] = float_1 + 100.0  # write
```

---

Here's a simple pure python (no cuda) example:

```py
>>> import ctypes
>>> floats = [100.0, 200.0, 300.0]  # array of python floats
>>> c_floats = (ctypes.c_float * len(floats))(*floats)  # array of ctypes floats
>>> p_floats =  ctypes.cast(c_floats, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))  # pointer to array of ctypes floats
>>> p_floats[0]  # read
100.0
>>> p_floats[1]  # read
200.0
>>> p_floats[2]  # read
300.0
>>> p_floats[2] = 400.0  # write index 2 (was 300.0)
>>> p_floats[2]  # read newly written index
400.0
>>> c_floats[2]  # check index 2 has been updated on the array itself
400.0
```

---

**[edit]**

> Can I do it by writing to all the indices at once?

You can't slice from a ctypes pointer but you can use [`ctypes.memmove()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.memmove).

Following previous example:

```py
>>> new_floats = [1000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0]
>>> c_new_floats = (ctypes.c_float * len(new_floats))(*new_floats)
>>> p_new_floats = ctypes.cast(c_new_floats, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
>>> ctypes.memmove(p_floats, p_new_floats, len(new_floats) * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float))  # copy new floats to previous array through pointers.
>>> p_floats[0]
1000.0
>>> p_floats[1]
2000.0
>>> p_floats[2]
3000.0
```

Comment: Can I do it by writing to all the indices at once?

Comment: The time taken by `ctypes.memmove()` is similar to `np.copyto()`